# Validating an input that do not suppose to allow decimals, it accepts 0.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am validating an input type number, it only must accepts values from `0` to `9999`. There can not be dots/decimals or anything like that.
I am doing it in a hacky way but it still throws an error when you enter `0.0`. The input can not receive any kind of special characters, only integer numbers from `0` to `9999`.

```js
// Initial value is an string
integersOnly(value) {
    // So I need to convert it to a number
    const turnValueIntoANumber = Number(value);
    return (isNaN(turnValueIntoANumber) || !Number.isInteger(turnValueIntoANumber)) && 'Only integers allowed';
}
```

The field:

```js
<Field
    min={0}
    max={9999}
    name="time"
    type="number"
    validate={[this.integersOnly]}
>
    TIME
</Field>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using formik .
what about using `yup` schema builder for validation.
check this :
[yup documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup)

you can use

```
yup.number().required().positive().integer()
```

Comment: I am using redux form. And I can not use yup.

Comment: what about this : https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-form-yup
@Reacting